# Laravel subdomain routes for multiple entity types

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a project which have multiple subdomains.
for example I have a subdomain for Students which goes to a student controller and it looks like this:

```
Route::domain('students.domain.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "done reaching the students page";
    });
});
```

The second type of domains is "domain.test" and any subdomain which I'm checking in the request level and that's fine too.

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

But before the second type of domains I want to make subdomain for specific types of Entities which I have in the database.

```
Route::domain('{someTypes}.domain.test')
->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "done reaching SomeTypes Page";
    });
});
```

My Entity table have these attributes: Id, Title, Type "which I want to check if the type is 5".

I tried to use the middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$types)
{
    $currentEntity = app('current_entity');
    if ($currentEntity->entityType()->whereIn('title->en', $types)->exists()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    abort(404, 'Sorry, Request Not Found');
}
```

and I applied it to my routes like this:

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => ['type:journal']
],function () {
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return 'journals logic goes here';
    });

});
```

and I have another middleware to ignore types like this:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$types)
{
    $currentEntity = app('current_entity');
    if ($currentEntity->entityType()->whereIn('title->en', $types)->exists()) {
        abort(404, 'Sorry, Request Not Found');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

and applied it to the other routes like this:

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => ['except_entity:journal']
], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){
    return 'default pages when journals fails';
})->name('index');
```

I hope its clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: what issue your getting here ?

Comment: I want to check that "someType" is the id on an Entity which its type is 5 not any other type

Comment: then create a middleware and perform that check

Comment: I have a middleware but it abort by 404 on the first type, Can I make it pass the result to the other route if the type failed for check ?

Comment: i think you should try with middleware and if not working then ask in `SO`

Comment: I already tried by the middleware and thats why Im asking now, The middleware block the first request and I have 2 routes I want to apply the middleware on.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need a check what version laravel that you used?

You need to use Middleware. And I think, method to code with laravel 6, 7, or 8, is a little bit different.

Can you give us more information about your code, so we can help it easier?

Comment: I use laravel 7. and I edited the post you can check it